# REST-Client: 302 Found when trying to pass XML-String

Tags: php, xml, rest

I want to implement a REST-Client which handles form input data and sends it to an REST Backend.

```
$strXml = file_get_contents($_FILES['xmlfile']['tmp_name']);
$service_url = 'api/index.php/pojects';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(
    "title" => $_POST['title'],
    "client" => $_POST['client'],
    "comment" => $_POST['comment'],
    "project_number" => $_POST['project_number'],
    "xml" => $strXml,
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($curl_response);
var_dump($strXml);
```

But it seems, that there's something wrong, maybe with the webserver config.
It says:

```
    302 Found
The document has moved here.
```

But the var_dump of the xml string is correct. What's my error in reasoning?

Comment: It's perhaps you do not understand the status message. 302 Found means that the location changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a redirect.. Add this **`cURL`** param

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```